# Is there a tool to pause/resume/seek MoveIt trajectories?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am planning robot trajectories using MoveIt, sometimes the path is very long and I want to see only a specific part of the trajectory.

Is there a tool in ROS that provides a seek bar and allows me to pause/resume trajectories?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238003/is-there-a-tool-to-pause/resume/seek-moveit-trajectories?/) by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1505 on 2016-06-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-25**:
Good question. I haven't seen something like that. It would be quite involved though: caching trajectories, sitting between MoveIt and whatever controller you have configured, recalculating `time_from_start` and velocity/accel profiles, etc.

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-07-20**:
@gvdhoorn should I open an issue on MoveIt issue tracker? This probably requires work in more packages than just MoveIt.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-20**:
I would suggest opening one on the MoveIt tracker. At the very least we can discuss there where this sort of functionality could/should live.

Although I expect the consensus will be: if there is no (re)planning involved, implement an action server that supports what you want and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

O wait. I missed this part:

> sometimes the path is very long and I want to see only a specific part

If it's really just about visualisation -- instead of execution, as I initially understood your question: that has actually recently been added. See [ros-planning/moveit#491](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/491).

The updated *MoveIt! RViz Plugin Tutorial* tutorial shows what this looks like now (in [Introspecting trajectory waypoints](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/quickstart_in_rviz/quickstart_in_rviz_tutorial.html#introspecting-trajectory-waypoints)):

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-07-20**:
My goal is to be able to pause/resume/seek the simulation. I'll take a look at this and try it!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-20**:
Afaik this is really just for visualisation.

For execution I don't think there is something.

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-07-24**:
I have tried it and it looks surprisingly easy at first sight. I won't select your answer as correct right now as I'm not sure yet how I can use it but it is certainly very useful. I will comment again when I understand more about how it works!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically the answer to your question depends on what you mean by "pause the simulation".

- Pause gazebo? That's easy.
- Pause the visualized trajectory in RViz? That's what the new Trajectory Slider is for.
- Pause MoveIt's demo mode? That's not as easy.
  We could add a new execution mode 'in rviz' (or something like that) to the [https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/kinetic-devel/moveit_plugins/moveit_fake_controller_manager](fake controller) (or write a new fake controller) and publish the last point displayed in RViz back to the fake controller.
  That way the fake controller could actually "execute" the Trajectory by showing it in RViz.
  That way you could pause the visualization in RViz and it would actually pause the execution.

It might be that you have to disable trajectory execution monitoring for this to work.
At the moment, I'm unsure whether MoveIt monitors the execution process of the fake controllers.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-24**:
I think the question is indeed really what "simulation" is supposed to mean here. If it's just the visualisation that RViz shows, then the slider would indeed suffice. For everything else more work will be needed.